# Add Google trust badge to Magento

Tags: php, magento, google-trusted-stores

I am trying to add Google Trust Badge to my magento store. I tried to search extension on Magento website, but I couldn't find one. Do I need to just paste the below code to the products and checkout page or I have to make changes to it? I will be very thankful if someone can guide me to right direction.

```
<!-- BEGIN: Google Trusted Store -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var gts = gts || [];

  gts.push(["id", "54785"]);
  gts.push(["google_base_offer_id", "ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ID"]);
  gts.push(["google_base_subaccount_id", "ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ACCOUNT_ID"]);
  gts.push(["google_base_country", "ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_COUNTRY"]);
  gts.push(["google_base_language", "ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_LANGUAGE"]);

  (function() {
    var scheme = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    var gts = document.createElement("script");
    gts.type = "text/javascript";
    gts.async = true;
    gts.src = scheme + "www.googlecommerce.com/trustedstores/gtmp_compiled.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gts, s);
  })();
</script>
<!-- END: Google Trusted Store -->


<!-- START Trusted Stores Order -->
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;">

  <!-- start order and merchant information -->
  <span id="gts-o-id">MERCHANT_ORDER_ID</span>
  <span id="gts-o-domain">MERCHANT_ORDER_DOMAIN</span>
  <span id="gts-o-email">CUSTOMER_EMAIL</span>
  <span id="gts-o-country">CUSTOMER_COUNTRY</span>
  <span id="gts-o-currency">CURRENCY</span>
  <span id="gts-o-total">ORDER_TOTAL</span>
  <span id="gts-o-discounts">ORDER_DISCOUNTS</span>
  <span id="gts-o-shipping-total">ORDER_SHIPPING</span>
  <span id="gts-o-tax-total">ORDER_TAX</span>
  <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">ORDER_EST_SHIP_DATE</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-preorder">HAS_BACKORDER_PREORDER</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-digital">HAS_DIGITAL_GOODS</span>
  <!-- end order and merchant information -->

  <!-- start repeated item specific information -->
  <!-- item example: this area repeated for each item in the order -->
  <span class="gts-item">
    <span class="gts-i-name">ITEM_NAME</span>
    <span class="gts-i-price">ITEM_PRICE</span>
    <span class="gts-i-quantity">ITEM_QUANTITY</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id">ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ID</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id">ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ACCOUNT_ID</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_COUNTRY</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_LANGUAGE</span>
  </span>
  <!-- end item 1 example -->
  <!-- end repeated item specific information -->

</div>
<!-- END Trusted Stores -->
```

Comment: So, you're ok with giving Google MORE info about your customers? (I know, a little off topic, but something to think about...)

Comment: hi @Paul I am sorry, but I am not suppose to put that code up? I just wanted to do more BUSINESS. Though, I am worried about my customers Privacy. I dont think Google will misuse it.

Comment: "I dont think Google will misuse it" - Misuse is such a subjective word! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has since been a Magento extension released by Google themselves: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-trusted-stores-3308.html

Comment: Be warned that this extension isn't what you'd hope for and hasn't been kept up to date.  Google recently revamped how their integration works (no longer dependent on feeds)--this extension still works but hasn't been updated, and uses an older .js api which may be getting phased out.

Answer (score 6):

[Implementing Google Trusted Stores](http://support.google.com/trustedstoresmerchant/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2609862): [#3 Add the JavaScript to Your Site](http://support.google.com/trustedstoresmerchant/bin/answer.py?answer=2609894):

Google actually wants you to put the first part on *every* page of your site. Rather than do this in a template file you can add it to the Footer > Miscellaneous HTML in System > Configuration > General > Design. I removed `ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ID` and `ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ACCOUNT_ID`, but feel free to edit your product page to add this data. Here's the code:

```
<!-- BEGIN: Google Trusted Store -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var gts = gts || [];

  gts.push(["id", "54785"]);
  gts.push(["google_base_country", "US"]);
  gts.push(["google_base_language", "en"]);

  (function() {
    var scheme = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    var gts = document.createElement("script");
    gts.type = "text/javascript";
    gts.async = true;
    gts.src = scheme + "www.googlecommerce.com/trustedstores/gtmp_compiled.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gts, s);
  })();
</script>
<!-- END: Google Trusted Store -->
```

[image: Screenshot of Magento System / Config / Design / Footer HTML]

The rest of the code only needs to be on the **Checkout Success** page (app/design/frontend/{your}/{theme}/template/checkout/success.phtml). We need to load the order to grab the customer's email, country, and order data. You'll need to implement logic to determine whether or not any items are on backorder, whether any of the items are downloads, and when the items will be shipped. Add this anywhere in that file:

```
<?php
    $orderId = $this->getOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
    $backorder = false; // some backorder logic
    $download = false; // some download logic
    $shipDate = new Zend_Date(); // some logic to determine ship date
?>
<!-- START Trusted Stores Order -->
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;">

<!-- start order and merchant information -->
<span id="gts-o-id"><?php echo $orderId; ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-domain">{www.yourstore.com}</span>
<span id="gts-o-email"><?php echo htmlentities($customer->getEmail()); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-country"><?php echo htmlentities($address->getCountryId()); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-currency">USD</span>
<span id="gts-o-total"><?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-discounts">-<?php echo $order->getDiscountAmount(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-shipping-total"><?php echo $order->getShippingAmount(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-tax-total"><?php echo $order->getTaxAmount(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-est-ship-date"><?php echo $shipDate->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-has-preorder"><?php echo $backorder ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-has-digital"><?php echo $download ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>
<!-- end order and merchant information -->

<!-- start repeated item specific information -->
<?php foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item): ?>
<span class="gts-item">
<span class="gts-i-name"><?php echo htmlentities($item->getName()); ?></span>
<span class="gts-i-price"><?php echo $item->getBasePrice(); ?></span>
<span class="gts-i-quantity"><?php echo (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(); ?></span>
<span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">US</span>
<span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">en</span>
</span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- end repeated item specific information -->

</div>
<!-- END Trusted Stores -->
```

Comment: Actually, Google wants to get the customer *shipping address*, not billing address, as they're interested in tracking whether you're shipping it properly.  Apparently I can't edit your post, but you might want to.

Comment: Still working for Magento 2+ years later! Thanks @nachito. The only problem I found was that your snippet doesn't allow for guest e-mails.

    `$email = $customer->getData('email');  
    $email_address2 = $address->getEmail();  
    if($email=="") $email = $email_address2;  `

Answer (score 2):

You can insert that code at the bottom of `app/design/frontend/default/USED_TEMPLATE/template/checkout/onepage.phtml` to have it appear on the final checkout page.

You need to fill the variables, using the Magento-functions and output them. For example:

```
// Magento .phtml-style
<?php $cart = Mage::getSingleton( 'checkout/cart' ); ?>
<span class="gts-i-quantity"><?php echo $cart->getItemsCount(); ?></span>`
```

Or you go the long way, using Magento hooks in an own extension to present the Google-snippet wherever you want, without the need to implement it in the templates.

Comment: This should actually be on the checkout *success* page, it does no good on the checkout page and `$cart->getItemsCount()` returns the number of items in your cart, not the quantity of the item ordered, as `gts-i-quantity` should be.

Comment: I don't know anything about that Google-code above. So I couldn't know where it would be placed best and `$cart->getItemsCount()` also is just an example.

Comment: Hi @feeela , I wrote an email to Google and they told me that the first code will go into footer and another one in order success page.

Answer (score 2):

The code definitely needs to be on the checkout success page in the app folder (app/design/frontend/*yourtheme*/template/checkout/success.phtml). I found my answer here for [magento badge implementation](http://www.lifetimemediagroup.com/2015/10/19/google-trusted-stores-on-magento/), but just like several answers suggest it is LOGIC that it is important and it is usually different for every store depending on the extension and custom dev you are running.

```
    <!– START Google Trusted Stores Order –>
<div id=”gts-order” style=”display:none;” translate=”no”>

<!– start order and merchant information –>
<span id=”gts-o-id”><?php echo $orderId; ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-domain”>[INSERT URL (www.example.com)]</span>
<span id=”gts-o-email”><?php echo htmlentities($customer->getEmail()); ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-country”><?php echo htmlentities($address->getCountryId()); ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-currency”>[USD]</span>
<span id=”gts-o-total”><?php echo round_and_kep($order->getGrandTotal()); ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-discounts”>[CALL IT OUT WITH CODE – use 0 if no discounts]</span>
<span id=”gts-o-shipping-total”><?php echo round_and_kep($order->getShippingAmount()); ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-tax-total”><?php echo round_and_kep($order->getTaxAmount()); ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-est-ship-date”><?php echo $shipDate->toString(‘yyyy-MM-dd’); ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-est-delivery-date”><?php echo $shipDate->toString(‘yyyy-MM-dd’); ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-has-preorder”><?php echo $backorder ? ‘Y’ : ‘N'; ?></span>
<span id=”gts-o-has-digital”><?php echo $download ? ‘Y’ : ‘N'; ?></span>
<!– end order and merchant information –>

<!– start repeated item specific information –>
<!– item example: this area repeated for each item in the order –>
<span class=”gts-item”>
<span class=”gts-i-name”><?php echo htmlentities($item->getName()); ?></span>
<span class=”gts-i-price”><?php echo round_and_kep($item->getBasePrice()); ?></span>
<span class=”gts-i-quantity”><?php echo (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(); ?></span>
<span class=”gts-i-prodsearch-id”>[ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ID]</span>
<span class=”gts-i-prodsearch-store-id”>[YOUR STORE ID GIVEN TO YOU BY GOOGLE]</span>
<span class=”gts-i-prodsearch-country”>US</span>
<span class=”gts-i-prodsearch-language”>en</span>
</span>
<!– end item 1 example –>
<!– end repeated item specific information –>

</div>
<!– END Google Trusted Stores Order –>
```